# R - created function does not output correctly

Tags: r, function, if-statement, datediff

I am attempting to find the difference between two dates and then group that value into factor levels. I have done this before with other numeric values but not dates and can't figure what I am doing incorrectly. I don't get any errors on the function creation but have tried two different ways to apply it.

I originally calculated it in days because I need a day value later on. Grouping it into weeks is to create some levels for visualization later.

```
#created Lead_time column to calculate how far in advance appointment was booked
#formated in days
df7$Lead_Time <- difftime(df7$Appointment_Date_Time, df7$appt_create_date, units = "days")
#to negate when negatives are created due to the appointment being created after the start time
df7$Lead_Time <- as.integer(df7$Lead_Time)

#group Lead_Time by weeks
group_Lead_Time <- function(Lead_Time){
  if (Lead_Time <= 28){
    return('0-4 Weeks')
  }else if(Lead_Time > 29 & Lead_Time <= 56){
    return('5-8 Weeks')
  }else if (Lead_Time > 57 & Lead_Time <= 84){
    return('8-12 Weeks')
  }else if (Lead_Time > 85 & Lead_Time <= 112){
    return('12-16 Weeks')
  }else if (Lead_Time > 113 & Lead_Time <=140){
    return('16-20 Weeks')  
  }else if (Lead_Time > 141 & Lead_Time <=168){
    return('20-24 Weeks')  
  }else if (Lead_Time > 168){
    return('24+ Weeks')
  }
}
df7$Lead_Time_Grouped <- as.factor(group_Lead_Time(df7$Lead_Time))
df7$Lead_Time_Grouped <- sapply(df7$Lead_Time,group_Lead_Time)
```

If someone has a better way to handle the negative values I am open to it as well.
These are the error messages I get:

```
> df7$Lead_Time_Grouped <- as.factor(group_Lead_Time(df7$Lead_Time))
Warning messages:
1: In if (Lead_Time <= 28) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (Lead_Time > 29 & Lead_Time <= 56) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (Lead_Time > 57 & Lead_Time <= 84) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (Lead_Time > 85 & Lead_Time <= 112) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> df7$Lead_Time_Grouped <- sapply(df7$Lead_Time,group_Lead_Time)
Error in if (Lead_Time <= 28) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

UPDATE/EDIT: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of ifelse. Was able to resolve my challenge with the code below.

```
#group Lead_Time by weeks
group_Lead_Time <- function(appt_lead_time){
  ifelse (appt_lead_time <= 28,'0-4 Weeks',
          ifelse (appt_lead_time > 29 & appt_lead_time <= 56, '5-8 Weeks',
                  ifelse (appt_lead_time > 57 & appt_lead_time <= 84, '8-12 Weeks',
                          ifelse (appt_lead_time > 85 & appt_lead_time <= 112, '12-16 Weeks',
                                  ifelse (appt_lead_time > 113 & appt_lead_time <=140, '16-20 Weeks',
                                      ifelse (appt_lead_time > 141 & appt_lead_time <=168, '20-24 Weeks',
                                              '24+ Weeks'))))))
                                                    
  }

df7$appt_lead_time_weeks <- group_Lead_Time(df7$appt_lead_time)
```

Comment: You may either `Vectorize` the function or use `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Comment: @akrun i am unclear how to implement either of your suggestions. looking at vectors I see use of c() to create the vector but I need to research further how or in what part of this code I would create said vector. Additionally I tried to use ifelse in place of if/else and it didn't work either. Thank you

Comment: Can you please update your post with a small reproducible example using `dput` so that it can be tested. thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I am first year at this stuff. I will have to research dput. I was really hoping it was just something I did wrong with the first if statement based on the error message

Comment: I am working with a very large data set and even picking just 5 observations the output of dput is more than what I can copy/paste from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the comments I was able to come up with the solution below:

```
#group Lead_Time by weeks
group_Lead_Time <- function(appt_lead_time){
  ifelse (appt_lead_time <= 28,'0-4 Weeks',
  ifelse (appt_lead_time > 29 & appt_lead_time <= 56, '5-8 Weeks',
  ifelse (appt_lead_time > 57 & appt_lead_time <= 84, '8-12 Weeks',
  ifelse (appt_lead_time > 85 & appt_lead_time <= 112, '12-16 Weeks',
  ifelse (appt_lead_time > 113 & appt_lead_time <=140, '16-20 Weeks',
  ifelse (appt_lead_time > 141 & appt_lead_time <=168, '20-24 Weeks',
                                              '24+ Weeks'))))))
  }

df7$appt_lead_time_weeks <- group_Lead_Time(df7$appt_lead_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little toy example that might help you out as well using `cut()`. This assumes you already calculated the Lead Times as an integer.

```r
# simulate some lead times between -10 and 200 days
set.seed(1234)
lead_times <- as.integer(round(runif(100, -10, 200), 0))

# convert all negatives to 0 (i.e., no lead time)
# you don't actually have to do this, but thought I would show it
lead_times_adj <- pmax(lead_times, 0)

# convert to weeks
lead_times_weeks <- lead_times_adj / 7

# use cut to break the data into factors by number of weeks
group_lead_time <- cut(lead_times_weeks, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, Inf),
                       labels = c("0-4 Weeks", "4-8 Weeks", "8-12 Weeks",
                                  "12-16 Weeks", "16-20 Weeks", "20-24 Weeks",
                                  "24+ Weeks"))

# create a data frame to show an example result
data.frame(Lead_Time = lead_times,
           Lead_Time_Grouped = group_lead_time)
```

So you would get something like this...

```
    Lead_Time Lead_Time_Grouped
1          14         0-4 Weeks
2         121       16-20 Weeks
3         118       16-20 Weeks
4         121       16-20 Weeks
5         171         24+ Weeks
6         124       16-20 Weeks
7          -8         0-4 Weeks
8          39         4-8 Weeks
9         130       16-20 Weeks
...
```

Comment: while I did find a solution that ultimately worked I do like this method as well and will store this for future reference. Thank you!